# How to write courier text using GDI and pure C?

Tags: c

I need to write text using the function TextOut() of Windows GDI, but using Courier font and not the default one. Can someone help me?

Comment: These should be useful: [CreateFontA function (wingdi.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfonta) [SelectObject function (wingdi.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject)

Answer (score 2):

The GDI commands to draw text use the font currently "selected into" the device context (DC).

To choose a font, you first need to create a description of the font you want.  That description is called a logical font ([LOGFONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logfontw)).  You can be very specific by giving the typeface name ("Courier New") or you can more generally request something like a monospace font.

Either way, we'll need the font size in device units.  This gets complicated by tricks the OS uses to make things work on high resolution displays, but this formula generally works:

> height_in_device_units = -height_in_points * pixels_per_vertical_inch / 72

The negative sign tells the system you're specifying the height of the text itself, not of the rectangle that contains the text.

```
LOGFONT lf = {0};
lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(point_size, GetDeviceCap(hDC, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
lstrcpy(lf.lfFaceName, "Courier New");
// There are many more fields of a LOGFONT, but we initialized them to 0,
// which is fine for what we need.
```

Once you have a logical font description, you need to get a handle to the font object.

```
HFONT hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
```

All this does is make a copy of the logical font description somewhere in the system.  Now, we want to select this font into the device context.

```
HGDIOBJ hOldFont = SelectObject(hDC, hFont);
```

This is where the system looks at the description of the font you want and tries to find the best match based on the fonts installed in the system, the DC's resolution, etc.  Note that SelectObject returns the handle of the object that you've just replaced.  In your case, this will be a handle to the system font, since that's the one that was pre-loaded into the DC.  We need to remember the old font, because we must restore it once we're done working with the DC.

So now we can draw our text at coordinates (x, y):

```
TextOut(hDC, x, y, TEXT("Hello, World!"), 13);
```

If you want text on consecutive lines, you'll need to figure out how far down to go.  You can get this by asking for the text metrics for the currently-selected font.

```
TEXTMETRIC tm;
GetTextMetrics(hDC, &tm);
int dy = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;

TextOut(hDC, x, y, TEXT("Hello"), 5);
TextOut(hDC, x, y+dy, TEXT("World!"), 6);
```

Don't forget to clean up when you're done drawing.  Before you release or destroy the device context, you need to put it back the way you found it.  That's why we remembered the original font object:

```
SelectObject(hDC, hOldFont);
```

And if you're not going to use it again, it's also a good time to delete the font object you created:

```
DeleteObject(hFont);
```

Note that you don't delete the old font, because the system made that one *and* because it's selected into a DC.  Never delete a GDI object that's still selected into a DC.  (And, generally speaking, you should almost never select the same object into two different DCs at the same time.)

There's a lot more to learn here.  But this will get your started.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you very much.